# How can I log timestamps with Varnish health probes?

Tags: linux, logging, varnish

I'm using Varnish 3.0.3 on RHEL 6 as a caching load balancer in front of several Apache web servers and want to keep a log of when Varnish sees the back-ends change from healthy to sick and back again.

From the command line I can run `varnishlog -O -I "Back healthy|Went sick"` and see lines like the following:

```
0 Backend_health - webserver1 Went sick 4--X--- 2 3 5 0.000000 0.000679 
0 Backend_health - webserver1 Back healthy 4--X-RH 3 3 5 0.000622 0.000679 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I'd love to write these sick/healthy state changes to a log file, but they are useless without having timestamps associated with them. How can I write these lines to a log file and include timestamps for each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `varnishlog` can be piped to awk and reformatted to put the date at the beginning of each line. The tricky part is that `varnishlog` buffers the output which causes it only to be sent to `awk` after a number of lines have been generated, resulting in all of the lines getting the same timestamp as the last one that tops off the buffer. To get around this, the `unbuffer` command can be used to pipe the output of `varnishlog` to `awk` straight away so that each line gets an appropriate timestamp.

```
unbuffer varnishlog -O -I 'Back healthy|Went sick' 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime(), $0; fflush() }'
```

This results in output like the following, which can then be appended to a log file.

```
Wed Feb 20 15:20:58 EST 2013     0 Backend_health - webserver1 Went sick 4--X--- 2 3 5 0.000000 0.000679
Wed Feb 20 15:28:03 EST 2013     0 Backend_health - webserver1 Back healthy 4--X-RH 3 3 5 0.000622 0.000679 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

*Note: Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21620/15872) [Kieron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588/kieron) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21907/15872) by [Mark Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116/mark-harrison) for the pieces needed to figure this out.*

Comment: On Debian you might want to use 'stdbuf' instead - with something like : 

stdbuf -o0 -i0 -e0 varnishlog -O -I 'PatternToMatch' 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime(), $0, fflush() }'