# Logging varnishlog output to a file with awk in daemon mode

Tags: linux, logging, varnish, awk

I would like to daemonize the answer in this topic https://serverfault.com/a/480871/94127. Since varnishlog has daemon mode, I tried to use -D option as  below. But the timestamps are not appearing.

```
varnishlog  -I "Back healthy|Went sick" -w /var/log/varnish_health.log -D | awk '{ print strftime(), $0; fflush()}'
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? I don't know varnishlog. Does -w make it read from that file or write to it? What does daemon mode mean? If the process detaches from the shell then it closes its /dev/stdout and thus the pipeline. awk never gets any input in that case. You need daemonize the whole pipeline by something like `nohup bash -c 'varnishlog ... | awk'` without daemonizing varnishlog itself, of course.

Comment: -w option writes to specified file and disables output to stdout, so your need to read from file with `tail -F`.

Comment: daemon = run in background. I will try the command you suggested. @AlexD, awk is adding in the timestamp to the varnishlog. If I use tail -F, I will lose correct time?

Comment: @antimatter, in your case awk isn't adding anything to varnishlog as it doesn't receive anything on stdin because -w redirects output to file instead of stdout. `tail -F` flushes its output after each line so it shouldn't affect timestamps much but `varnishlog` itself can buffer its output to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
{ varnishlog -I "Back healthy|Went sick" | awk '{ print strftime(), $0; fflush()}' >> /var/log/varnish_health.log; } & disown
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Here's my exact code for the record.Added unbuffer so that varnishlog will not buffer it.  `{ unbuffer varnishlog -i Backend_health -I "Back healthy|Went sick" | awk '{ print strftime(), $0; fflush()}' >> /var/log/varnish_health.log; } & disown`